# postgresql for loop script in text form can not be executed

Tags: postgresql, for-loop, execute, control-structure

I am trying to write function in postgresql, that creates temp_table with columns table_name text, table_rec jsonb and fill it through for loop with table names from my table containing names of tables and records in json. I have the for loop in string and I want to execute it. **But it doesnt work.**
I have variable rec record, sql_query text and tab_name text and I want to do this:

```
     CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.test51(
    )
    RETURNS TABLE(tabel_name text, record_json jsonb) 
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'

    COST 100
    VOLATILE 
    ROWS 1000
    
AS $BODY$
declare
rec record;
tabel_name text;
tabel_names text[];
counter integer := 1;
sql_query text;
limit_for_sending integer;
rec_count integer;
begin
select into tabel_names array(select "TABLE_NAME" from public."TABLES");
create temp table temp_tab(tab_nam text, recik jsonb);

while array_length(tabel_names, 1) >= counter loop

tabel_name := '"' || tabel_names[counter] || '"';

select into limit_for_sending "TABLE_LIMIT_FOR_SENDING_DATA" from public."TABLES" where "TABLE_NAME" = tabel_name;

sql_query := 'select count(*) from public.' || tabel_name;

execute sql_query into rec_count;

if (rec_count >= limit_for_sending and limit_for_sending is not null) then

sql_query := 'for rec in select * from public.' || tabel_name || '
loop
    insert into temp_tab
    select ' || tabel_name || ', to_jsonb(rec);
end loop';

execute sql_query;

end if;

counter := counter + 1;

end loop;

return query
select * from temp_tabik;

drop table temp_tabik;
end;
$BODY$;
```

Thank you for response.

Comment: Thank you for responese. I know the temp_table is useless. The function isnt final and I didnt want to create new table. Iam curious about executing the variable sql_script. I know I can execute DDL and DML scripts but I dont know, if I can execute for loops and conditions the same way. I will update the code now.

Comment: "But it doesnt work. ..... and I want to do this:  (some sql code)" ? And now we need to guess what you want to do with that code ?  Try to make your question into an [mre]. Add sample input and expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you have some table that contains the information for which tables you want to return all rows as JSONB. And that meta-table also contains a column that sets a threshold under which the rows should not be returned.

You don't need the temp table or an array to store the table names. You can iterate through the query on the `TABLES` table and run the dynamic SQL directly in that loop.

`return query` in PL/pgSQL doesn't terminate the function, it just appends the result of the query to the result of the function.

Dynamic SQL is best created using the `format()` function because it is easier to read and using the `%I` placeholder will properly deal with quoted identifiers (which is really important as you are using those dreaded upper case table names)

As far as I can tell, your function can be simplified to:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.test51()
    RETURNS TABLE(tabel_name text, record_json jsonb) 
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS 
$BODY$
declare
  rec record;
  sql_query text;
  rec_count bigint;
begin
  for rec in 
      select "TABLE_NAME" as table_name, "TABLE_LIMIT_FOR_SENDING_DATA" as rec_limit
      from public."TABLES"
  loop
    
    if rec.rec_limit is not null then 
      execute format('select count(*) from %I', rec.table_name)
        into rec_count;
    end if;
    
    if (rec.rec_limit is not null and rec_count >= rec.rec_limit) then 
      sql_query := format('select %L, to_jsonb(t) from %I as t', rec.table_name, rec.table_name);
      return query execute sql_query;
    end if;

  end loop;
end;
$BODY$;
```

---

Some notes

- the language name is an identifier and should not be enclosed in single quotes. This syntax is deprecated and might be removed in a future version so don't get used to it.
- you should really avoid those dreaded quoted identifiers. They are much more trouble than they are worth it. See [the Postgres wiki](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_upper_case_table_or_column_names) for details.

Comment: Thank you very much. Every bit of information you posted is really valuable for me as I am just a beginner in postgres and databases at all. This will help me to solve a problem at work :) thank you

Comment: Done, I am sorry, this was my first use of stack overflow so I dont know the ropes here. Thank you again for your answer and have a nice day.